# Printf displays this � whenever I use extended ascii(unsigned char)

Tags: c, printf, extended-ascii

I want to use some extended ASCII characters o I used unsigned char. There were no compiler errors, but it just displays �

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "PrintColor.h"

unsigned char background_occupacy[101] = {178,178,177,'@','@','@','@','W','W','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','B','Q','G','P','N','N','&','O','D','g','S','E','m','w','A','8','Z','K','H','6','9','X','C','p','b','q','5','U','2','O','e','3','a','V','V','F','4','h','k','o','s','y','u','n','n','c','T','z','z','7','J','x','L','L','v','?','?','=','f','t','t','j',')','(','(','r','r','i','^','/','*','_',';',';',':','-',',','.','.',' ',' ',' ',' '};

int main(){
  text_color(5);
  background_color(5);

  for(int j = 0; j < 8; j ++){
  text_color(8 - j);
  background_color(j);
  for(int i = 101; i > -1; i --){
    printf("%c",background_occupacy[i]);
  }

  text_color(j);
  background_color(8 - j);

  for(int i = 0; i < 101; i ++){
    printf("%c",background_occupacy[i]);
  }
  reset();
  printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Whichever character encoding you refer to when you say "extended ASCII" is not the same as the character encoding used by your terminal (or possibly the font used by the terminal just doesn't include the character you want).

Answer (score 1):

I think here could be some problims like:
Your terminal has it own encoding, so if you want to output "special" chars - make sure that your terminal can output it.

So, if you are Windows user - change the code page or use casts to another encoding.
If you are not windows user - try to use this library:
https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

---

Comment: I'm using windows terminal. Is there a way to enable it for that?

Comment: ``c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wchar_t char= <unicode value>;
    wprintf(L"%lc\n", char);
}
``

Comment: if I have a header in which I change attributes of printf (like its colour), do I have to change that header to wprintf as well?